# How to hang a projector screen from a thin horizontal part of slightly curved ceiling

Tags: concrete, brick, drill, hanging, anchor

I have a brick wall in front of which I want to hang a projector screen. Here is an image of a typical projector screen that I am looking to buy:
[image: Image of projector screen]

The part of my ceiling near the wall is curved(the ceiling becomes horizontal only in the middle part of the room), however there is a thin horizontal part(3 inches thick/wide, where I mean thickness as the perpendicular distance of the outer tip from the brickwall, see image for clarification; the actual depth of concrete or vertical thickness is much more) of the ceiling that directly joins the wall, see the following pictures:

[image: Picture of the wall]

[image: Explaing the curvature of the ceiling]

I don't have any DIY experience before this, so please help me go through the steps. From what I have researched on the internet, I think I should install two hangers along with S-type hooks on that 3-inch part of the ceiling using sleeve anchors, and then hang my projector screen using those two hooks. The screen should be between 15 to 20 pounds in weight. Am I correct in my basic plan? Or should I hang it from the brick wall? What kind of equipments will I need for this job?

This is a university apartment, and I would like this job to have as little damage as possible(I would ideally like to remove or at least hide/paint the screws when I leave the apartment eventually). As I said, I have not done any drilling/hanging before, and will have to buy all equipments afresh(I don't even have a driller with me), so a detailed walkthrough of the process would be much appreciated.

Comment: What material is the 3" wide section and the rest of the ceiling made of?

Comment: You mentioned concrete; see [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/installing-an-18kg-40lb-projector-screen-onto-a-concrete-ceiling?lq=1), and check the link in the comment appearing there.

Comment: That link mentions using a rawl-bolt. From what I could find, it is similar to a sleeve anchor, right? My current plan is to drill a hole with a hammer drill, install a sleeve anchor in it, and then somehow install a hook using it that can hold the triangular hook on the top of the screen(see the image of the projector screen in the OP, there are two triangular hooks that need to be hung from the ceiling). However, I cannot seem to find any eye-bolt or hook that is oriented in a way that it can be secured from the ceiling with a bolt. All hooks and eyebolt that I can find are wall-mountable.

Comment: The rawl bolt whose picture is in that link of the other question has a eye-bolt built-in, which would do my job(as I can hang a S-hook from it, but how would I install it? Can I simply hammer on the bottom of the eye-bolt and will it be safe? Also, where can I find it? I can't seem to find a site that carries such a bolt.

Comment: [eye bolt sleeve anchor](https://www.google.com/search?q=sleve+anchor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=eye+bolt+sleeve+anchor&spell=1), a closed eye would be best, though probably unnecessary. Use a masonry drill bit to make the CORRECT SIZED hole, gently tap it in and then tighten the nut.

Answer (score 1):

For a damage-free install, I would forget about screwing anything in to the wall or ceiling. Make a free-standing frame out of lumber.

Comment: There are already some screws/nails in the apartment from the previous resident. So, I don't think it is a big deal if the things I mount aren't too pronounced to be visible from afar or if I can hide any holes after removing them. I have already wasted money on a tripod type stand, there were some issues with it. I think getting a conventional screen and hanging it conventionally is my best solution. So please don't mind about damage unless it's going to be a very big damage.

Answer (score 1):

Stud (wedge) anchors w/ nuts and washers: ([BoltDepot.com](https://www.boltdepot.com/Anchoring_products.aspx), contains a nice pictorial of the different types of anchors)

[image]

I can't find an eye bolt wedge anchor. These would need a [coupling nut](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%2F4%2020%20couppling%20nut&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=coupling%20nut), a separate eye bolt and go way beyond the strength required here. Those that I did find have minimum orders starting at 1000...

Or, as you found; Mad Rock Sentinel Hangers: ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007HHPBHG))

[image]

---

Sleeve Anchor Eye Bolt: ([Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/350817869684?lpid=82))

[image]

These are not (dry)wall anchors, they are masonry fasteners acceptable in both vertical or horizontal applications, depending on load (your load is negligible either way).

Comment: Just before I saw your answer, I had settled on using a 3/8" sleeve anchor [HomeDepot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Red-Head-3-8-in-x-3-in-Hex-Head-Sleeve-Anchors-15-Pack-11013/100025194?quantity=1) to mount this [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007HHPBHG/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A2EG6QEDZDPFVD), and then hang the screen on it using S-hooks, [HomeDepot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lehigh-50-lb-3-16-in-x-1-3-4-in-Zinc-Plated-Steel-S-Hooks-2-Pack-7060S-6/100158398?quantity=1&str_nbr=0367). What do you think about that?

Comment: Also, notice that I can't use that Sleeve Anchor Eye Bolt that you linked without using a S-hook also.

Comment: Also, do you think that thin part of the ceiling will withstand this load comfortably? I believe that it is completely filled with concrete, and there is one more floor above it(I am on the 1st floor).

Comment: @Ph3N0M - Be aware that the type of sleeve anchors that are shown can be very difficult to remove once they have been installed. The only really feasible methods are: 1) To pre-drill the install holes two times deeper then required and then cut it off and pound the remaining portion into the wall and leave it there. 2) Without a deep hole the only course is to cut it off flush with the wall and then pound it in a little bit.

Comment: @Ph3N0M Mike's suggestions should be heeded about easing removal. I think you're going to need S-hooks no matter what type you use (crimp them closed so it doesn't come flying off when it snaps up). I'd hope the concrete is sound; you live under it ;) Those sentinel hangers you found are pretty neat.